# Cascading drop down list in asp.net mvc 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to implement cascading drop down list in asp.net mvc 2.0 from database.
i had implementated it on mvc 1.0 but its not working in mvc 2.0
thank you.

Comment: You may want to add a little more detail, such as how you implemented it and in what way it's not working (i.e. what error is occurring).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the upgrade wizard to update your code to use MVC 2.0?

[Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Application to ASP.NET MVC 2](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/)